# WriteStream a dataFrame to Elasticsearch behind an Azure API Management that requires a client certificate?

Tags: azure, apache-spark, elasticsearch, pyspark, spark-structured-streaming

We have an environment where we have Elasticsearch that is protected behind Azure API Management. We have this locked down with client certificate requirements (as well as other security measures). Calls that come into APIM w/o the client cert are rejected.

I have a new system I am brining online where data is stored in Delta Lake tables and processed with PySpark (using Azure Synapse). At the end of the processing, I want to push the final product to Elasticsearch. I know that I can write to es using org.elasticsearch.spark, but I don't see any way that I can include a client certificate to be able to clear the APIM.

Are any of these possible?

1. Include a certificate when making the connection to Elasticsearch for the writeStream.
2. Use .Net to do the the streaming reads and writes. I am not yet sure what capabilities Microsoft.Spark has and if it can read from Delta tables with structured streaming. If it does work, I can use my existing libraries for calling to ES.
3. Find a way to peer the VNets so that I can call ES via a local IP address. I am doing this in another sytem, but in that case, I have access to both VNets. With Synapse, the Spark Pook is managed and I don't think it supports the Azure VNet peering functionality.
4. Something else?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I have found was to enable a Private Link Service on the Load Balancer in the cluster where I am running Elasticsearch, then create a Managed Private Endpoint connected to the PLS in Synapse.